# Read a output which should be only numeric

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In unix, i need to read a o/p which should be numeric, if suppose user entered character it should throw error as "invalid identifier". Is that possible in if loop?

Comment: Yes. Read the input, then check that it is valid (e.g. only made of digits).

Comment: for eg: please enter the number:
A
enter the valid number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
unset get_num
while [[ ! ${get_num} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter in a number:"
    read get_num
done
echo This is a number :  ${get_num}
```